# IE 11, Iframe pdf vs dialog box, z-index issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe, z-index

I have an Iframe which fetches code from other file and embeds pdf file in it. Now i have to display a dialog box/modal on it. I have tried z-index and position absolute and relative, but nothing is working out.

It is working fine in chrome and firefox, but my requirement is for IE 11.

Thanks in advance.